# Python - multiprocessing max # of processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to create and run at most N processes at once.
**As soon as a process is finished, a new one should take its place.**
The following code works(assuming Dostuff is the function to execute).
The problem is that I am using a loop and need time.sleep to allow
the processes to do their work. This is rather ineficient.
What's the best method for this task?

```
import time,multiprocessing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Jobs = []
    for i in range(10):
            while len(Jobs) >= 4:
                    NotDead = []
                    for Job in Jobs:
                            if Job.is_alive():
                                    NotDead.append(Job)
                    Jobs = NotDead
                    time.sleep(0.05)
            NewJob = multiprocessing.Process(target=Dostuff)
            Jobs.append(NewJob)
            NewJob.start()
```

After a bit of tinkering, I thought about creating new threads and then
launching my processes from these threads like so:

```
import threading,multiprocessing,time

def processf(num):
    print("in process:",num)
    now=time.clock()
    while time.clock()-now < 2:
        pass ##..Intensive processing..

def main():
    z = [0]
    lock = threading.Lock()
    def threadf():
        while z[0] < 20:
            lock.acquire()
            work = multiprocessing.Process(target=processf,args=(z[0],))
            z[0] = z[0] +1
            lock.release()
            work.start()
            work.join()

    activet =[]
    for i in range(2):
        newt = threading.Thread(target=threadf)
        activet.append(newt)
        newt.start()
    for i in activet:
        i.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This solution is better(doesn't slow down the launched processes), however,
I wouldn't really trust code that *I wrote* in a field I *don't* know..
I've had to use a list(z = [0]) since an integer was immutable.
Is there a way to embed processf into main()? I'd prefer not needing an additional
global variable. If I try to simply copy/paste the function inside, I get a nasty error(
Attribute error can't pickle local object 'main.(locals).processf')

Comment: Have you looked at [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`? 

`executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
res = execuror.submit(any_def)`